# Visual Studio 2013 - Edit Project Template

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013

I've created a new template by "File -> Export template" command. I want source file name to be such as project name, so, I've edited ".vstemplate" file. But now - how do I use this updated template? Seems like VS keeps copies of templates somewhere else, because after restarting VS - nothing changed. 
By the way, in VS2012 by developer command prompt was possible to install modified templates by the command "devenv /installvstemplates". Now, this command is gone, it is not a command or a file. 
So, how can I use this updated template file?

Comment: What version of VS are you using? The community (free) versions do not support the `/installvstemplates` options.

Answer (score 2):

The Community/Express (free) versions do not support the `/installvstemplates` options.

If you are using another version, the steps for customising an existing template are as follows (taken from my blog here: http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?p=527):

**1. Find the files**

The files have not moved around much so are currently in `C:\<Program Files>\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033`

(in VS2012 they are in `C:\<Program Files>\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033`)

The file you want is in an appropriately named folder (no more ZIP files!). If you open the Class folder you will find the following 2 files:

```
Class.cs
Class.vstemplate
```

**2. Backup the original files!**

Very important step as things do go wrong. Backup the original files e.g. by copying it to Class.cs. Orig so that it is not recognised by Visual Studio.

**3. Change the Class.cs template file**

This is where you get to be creative. You will notice the original looks something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

You might want something more like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $safeitemrootname$
    {
        #region Constants
        #endregion Constants

        #region Fields
        #endregion Fields

        #region Properties
        #endregion Properties

        #region Constructors
        #endregion Constructors

        #region Public methods
        #endregion Public methods

        #region Class override methods
        #endregion Class override methods

        #region Class extensions - virtual methods
        #endregion Class extensions - virtual methods

        #region Private helper methods
        #endregion Private helper methods
    }
}
```

You will notice a number of Macros $ commands in the template. The complete list is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx.

**4. Save your changes**
Simply save your edited files (again, there is no longer a ZIP file to re-compress with VS 2012/2013).

**5. Tell Visual Studio about the changes**
Your new changes will not be loaded unless you explicitly tell Visual Studio to reload all templates.

- Close Visual Studio (or the change swill not show until next time you run it)
- Open a command prompt (you should run this as Administrator if you are not an admin of the machine).
- Change to the IDE folder a few levels above the template folder (e.g. to `C:\<Program Files>\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE`)
- Run the following command: `devenv.exe /installvstemplates`
- Viola! There you have your own custom template for new classes.

**6. Automate repetitive/fiddly  tasks**

If you are going to do this a lot I would suggest creating a batch file, e.g. in your template folder, to run the update step for you. For example create a text file called UpdateTemplates.bat containing the following 3 lines:

```
cd "C:\Prograsm Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common\IDE\"
devenv.exe /installvstemplates
pause
```

Comment: I am using VS 2013 Express. By the way, I have no folder for "C/C++" in "C:\<Program Files>\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\". So, with VS2013E I can do nothing?